# Spring data mongodb @DBRef list

Tags: spring, mongodb, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, dbref

I am trying to have a list in a model using `@DBRef` but I can't get it to work.
This is my User model:

```
@Data
@Document
public class User {

    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    private ObjectId id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @NotBlank
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    @DBRef
    private List<Server> servers;
}
```

Server model:

```
@Data
@Document
public class Server {

    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    private ObjectId id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String host;
}
```

The structure is very simple, every user can have multiple servers. But when I add servers to the user the server is created, but the servers array contains one `null` entry(`"servers" : [ null ]`). So the server isn't added to the user. This is how I create a server and add it to an user:

```
@PostMapping
public Mono create(@Valid @RequestBody Server server, Mono<Authentication> authentication) {
    return this.serverRepository.save(server).then(authentication.flatMap(value -> {
        User user = (User) value.getDetails();
        user.getServers().add(server);

        return userRepository.save(user);
    })).map(value -> server);
}
```

So I simply create and save a server, add the server the user and then save the user. But it doesn't work. I keep having an array with one `null` entry.

I've seen this page: http://www.baeldung.com/cascading-with-dbref-and-lifecycle-events-in-spring-data-mongodb. But it is for saving the child document, not for linking it. Also it is for a single document, not for an array or list.

Why is my list not being saved correctly?

All my libraries are coming from spring boot version `2.0.0.M6`.

**UPDATE**
When removing `@DBRef` from the user's servers property the servers are getting saved, but they of course get double created, in the `server` collection and in every `user.servers`. So the error has something to do with references.

Comment: can you put Authentication class also, so that we can try the code as it is  from our end

Comment: the above code works for me

Comment: @pvpkiran The Authentication interface is from spring(`org.springframework.security.core.Authentication`)

Comment: @pvpkiran When I edit other properties from the user object it works fine, it is only the Server list that doesn't work.

Comment: can you check if  `user.getServers()` returns you a list ?

Comment: For me it works. In database i can see it is stored like this `"servers" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "server",
            "$id" : ObjectId("5a15b629ad242a61ae690858")
        }
    ],`

Comment: @pvpkiran `getServers()` is not a list but null, I added a check before the add that creates an empty list, but still not stored... The code I posted is almost literately what you need to replicate it... I have all mongodb settings on default. In stead on `Authentication` I replaces it with `userService.findById(new ObjectId("existing id"))` but still the servers isn't saved correctly... What version are you using?

Comment: @pvpkiran I created a fully fresh spring boot webflux project and did the same as in this question, but it still doesn't work... How did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

After some googling I found the answer...
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1583
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1584

Reactive mongo doesn't support this.

Comment: This is strange. Because. The way I tested is instead of sending it over a rest call, I hardcoded the value(User, Server and Authentication) and triggered the function using the rest call(with no arguments). But I have kept the reactive piece of code as it is. And that works. Not sure how that changes the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to resolve DbRefs without to using the blocking driver. Yes - the references are resolved in a blocking fashion, but does not require a second connection. In order to achieve this we have to write our own DbRefResolver: NbDbRefResolver.java. In the provided resolver there is a flag: RESOLVE_DB_REFS_BY_ID_ONLY. If is switched on will not going to resolve the DbRefs from the database, but instead will resolve them to fake objects with id only. It is up to implementation to fill the references later in non-blocking fashion.

If the flag RESOLVE_DB_REFS_BY_ID_ONLY is set to false it will eagerly resolve the references by using the non-blocking driver, but will block the execution until the references are resolved.
Here is how to register the DbRefResolver in the app: DbConfig.kt

Files attached are provided here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1584

Answer (score 0):

Me did it like that for roles :

```
  @Unwrapped(onEmpty = Unwrapped.OnEmpty.USE_NULL)
  private Collection<Role> roles;
```

you can check the doc (2021) here : https://spring.io/blog/2021/04/20/what-s-new-in-spring-data-2021-0